# How to delay page refresh after submitting a form

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress, forms

I have a form that uploads the profile image to wordpress. After form submit, the page is refreshed and the old image is displayed again. I have to wait about 4 or 5 seconds for the new image to appear. So I have to refresh the page 2 times to see the new image set.

I want to delay the refresh of the page but not the submission of the form, in this way I believe that you don't have to refresh the page twice to see the changes.

I tried with a script, but it doesn't work. I apologize for all this but i am new and i don't have much knowledge about php or js, can anyone help me?

```
<form id="wpua-edit-<?php echo esc_attr( $user->ID ); ?>" class="wpua-edit" action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  
  <input type="hidden" name="wp-user-avatar" id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wp-user-avatar' : 'wp-user-avatar-existing' ) ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $wpua ); ?>" />

            <div class="upload-avatar" id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-upload-button' : 'wpua-upload-button-existing' ); ?>">
                <input name="wpua-file" id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-file' : 'wpua-file-existing' ); ?>" type="file" class="wp-input-file"/>
                <button type="submit" class="button" id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-upload' : 'wpua-upload-existing' ); ?>" name="submit" value="<?php esc_html_e( 'Aggiorna', 'one-user-avatar' ); ?>">
                    <?php esc_html_e( 'Upload', 'one-user-avatar' ); ?>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-images' : 'wpua-images-existing' ); ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $hide_images ); ?>">
            <p id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-remove-button' : 'wpua-remove-button-existing' ); ?>" class="<?php echo esc_attr( $hide_remove ); ?>">
               <button type="button" class="button" id="<?php echo esc_attr( ( 'add-new-user' == $user ) ? 'wpua-remove' : 'wpua-remove-existing' ); ?>" name="wpua-remove"><?php esc_html_e( 'Remove Image', 'one-user-avatar' ); ?></button>
            </p>
            </div>
            
            <input type="hidden" name="wpua_action" value="update" />
            <input type="hidden" name="user_id" id="user_id" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $user->ID ); ?>" />

            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'update-user_' . $user->ID ); ?>
            <?php submit_button( __( 'Update Profile', 'one-user-avatar' ) ); ?>
            
</form>


<script>
jQuery.noConflict();
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    
    $("wpua-edit-<?php echo esc_attr( $user->ID ); ?>").submit(function() {
     //your code....
     setTimeout(function() {
         window.location.reload();
      }, 5000);
   });


});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have to upload an image and want to wait until it is uploaded before you reload the site, I would work with Ajax ([XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)) and send the image via JavaScript to the server. Then you can wait until it is uploaded and the reload the site.

Comment: Thanks for your intervention. The point is, I really don't know where to start, can I find an example code somewhere?

Comment: Try searching something like "example image upload ajax" at google. If you don't find something that helps you, you are welcome to come back to stackoverflow and ask.